# Reduce the amount of entries read for the smallest Levenshtein distance in a data bank

Tags: c#, string, filter, levenshtein-distance

I try to find an algorithm that calculates the minimal Levenshtein distance in a data bank very fast and does as much work as possible before I know the input string.

I have an algorithm that reads strings with an OCR algorithm. This algorithm makes a lot of mistakes. I have a data bank that consists of the strings I try to find with the OCR algorithm. This data bank is growing consistently. It is possible and also pretty likely that the read string is not part of that data bank, even if it is perfectly read by the OCR algorithm. In most cases, the string with the smallest Levenshtein distance will result in the most likely match in the data bank. So until now, I calculated the Levenshtein distance of the read string with every single entry in the data bank using the Wagner-Fischer algorithm. Sadly, this is the only time-critical part of the application and it takes a while. So I was wondering if I could speed up this part by pre-ordering the data bank in a certain way so that I could calculate the smallest Levenshtein distance in a data bank faster. Of course this pre-structuring would take a while itself, but the most critical part is the time between reading the string and finding the closest match in the data bank.

I try to find an algorithm to pre-structure the data of the data bank in a way, that I have to touch a minimal number of entries.

Is there a good way to improve the amount of strings I have to touch from the data bank? Can I structure the strings from the data bank in a certain way so that it excludes other strings efficiently for short strings?

Comment: Not sure if there's much research on this topic, but if you pre-calculate the distance between elements in your database, you might be able to hill climb towards better matches without comparing everything?

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman
You are right. That's the point of the question, but the issue is the order in which you can climb towards better matches. I struggle with the question of how to structure that to maximize the effect.

Comment: If you create clusters of clusters with smaller and smaller distances towards one another, you could arrange them in a tree-like formation with descending representatives for those clusters, because if one distance becomes too big, every string in the cluster will violate the rule and be too big. This would result in the whole cluster being excluded from the search.

Comment: For example: If you have a lot of strings of size 20, you can cluster Strings together that have a total distance of 15. If you find out that the distance towards one of the strings is 20, you can confirm that the distance to every other string is at least 5 as well. So if you already found one string with a distance of 5, you can guarantee that the cluster would never contain a better solution than you already have.

Comment: Questions come up like: How do you iterate through the descending representatives? You would probably want to maximize the distance between each individual comparison. How would you iterate through the clusters? You would probably start with smaller clusters so that you can exclude the bigger clusters on a higher level.

Comment: How do you decide which element should be part of a cluster? If you have strings like {"uuuu", "uuu8", "uu88", "u888", "8888"} a cluster would have a distance of 4 equal to the maximum distance, but each element only has a distance of 1 further down the road.

Comment: I could even think of a graph that uses BFS. Would arranging the nodes and edges of the graph for a bigger number of strings be a problem that is solvable after the end of the universe or is there a solution that is good enough to be practical?

Comment: Or you evaluate a different metric for your database that is easier to reason about. Similar to `SOUNDEX`, transforming each value into something you can then compare. But I have no idea if a levenshtein distance or similar metric is possible to transform in this way.

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman
That is a very interesting idea and also changes the perspective from looking for fewer differences to finding more similarities.

Comment: I don't know if it works or if I made a mistake, but my current idea so far would be to create an array for each character that is used in my data bank. I create a new array for each time it is contained. Each element of the data bank will be added to the array if it contains that character. This gives me a lot of arrays, but exactly (size(string)*numberOfStrings) entries. While searching for the smallest distance, I loop through each character of the search string.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but if I can invert Wagner-Fischer to search for similarities, I can then apply the inverted Wagner-Fischer until the point where the character in the search string and the corresponding character of the data-bank string sits. I save the current state of Wagner-Fischer in its nxm-matrix-form. If I hit another time, I can continue, where I stopped.

Comment: The element with the smallest distance is the element where (max(sizeOfString,sizeOfSearchstring) - numberOfSimilarities) is smallest. I use (numberOfSimilarities - max(sizeOfString,sizeOfSearchstring)) to represent certain buckets. Each time I increase the numberOfSimilarities for that string, I add it to the next bucket. The element that reaches the bucket with the highest number (ideally 0) is the element with the smallest distance.

Comment: If I made no mistake, each operation that I apply during the search for the smallest distance should be possible in constant time. That means the complexity class of the algorithm doesn't change. But what changes is the number of characters I touch, since I only apply Wagner-Fischer if I have a hit.

Comment: This algorithm could be improve by skipping every string where (numberOfCharactersLeftOfTheSearchString + currentBucketNumber  - max(sizeOfString,sizeOfSearchstring) < currentHighestBucketNumber ) since it cannot reach the highest bucket anymore. This would also mean that the algorithm doesn't calculate the distance for every entry in the data bank but only for the entry with the smallest distance.

Comment: SO isn't the right place for this discussion, perhaps you should try somewhere like https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/